# WebRTC and RTCPeerConnection works on Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm working on a video communication between two browsers, and recently I encountered a strange behavior of Firefox.

I have the very simple example of a RTCPeerConnection:

https://jsfiddle.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/

It works perfectly fine on Chrome but not on Firefox. Take a note that these browsers use different events to start a stream (*ontrack* vs *onaddstream*). To test the code on specific browser in jsfiddle you have to comment the section for the other one.

```
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(),
pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

var add = (pc, can) => can && pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(failed);
pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);

//      FIREFOX
pc2.ontrack = function(e) {
    console.log("ontrack");
    v2.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    v2.play();
};

//      CHROME
/*pc2.onaddstream = function (e) {
    console.log("onaddstream");
    v2.srcObject = e.stream;
    v2.play();
};*/

pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => log(pc1.iceConnectionState);

function start() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: false
        })
        .then(stream => pc1.addStream(v1.srcObject = stream))
        .then(() => pc1.createOffer())
        .then(offer => pc1.setLocalDescription(offer))
        .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
        .then(() => pc2.createAnswer())
        .then(answer => pc2.setLocalDescription(answer))
        .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
        .catch(failed);
}

function onTrack() {

};

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
var failed = e => log(e + ", line " + e.lineNumber);
```

I'm working on this issue for a couple of days now and I'm running out of ideas. I believe there is some basic stuff I just don't see :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: Here is my log from about:webrtc

```
Exit UDP socket connected
UDP socket error:Internal error at /build/firefox-Pa1eQI/firefox-57.0~b9/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:283 this=0x7fc9db14cc00
/build/firefox-Pa1eQI/firefox-57.0~b9/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3
ICE(PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3
/build/firefox-Pa1eQI/firefox-57.0~b9/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3
ICE(PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3
Exit UDP socket connected
UDP socket error:Internal error at /build/firefox-Pa1eQI/firefox-57.0~b9/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:283 this=0x7fc9e69ba400
/build/firefox-Pa1eQI/firefox-57.0~b9/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3
ICE(PC:1512747953848021 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3
ICE(PC:1512747953848021 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): peer (PC:1512747953848021 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/):default) no streams with non-empty check lists
ICE(PC:1512747953848021 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): peer (PC:1512747953848021 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/):default) no streams with pre-answer requests
ICE(PC:1512747953848021 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): peer (PC:1512747953848021 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/):default) no checks to start
ICE(PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): peer (PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/):default) no streams with non-empty check lists
ICE(PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): peer (PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/):default) no streams with pre-answer requests
ICE(PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/)): peer (PC:1512747953846868 (id=2147483738 url=https://fiddle.jshell.net/twardakm/bokj6gca/show/):default) no checks to start

+++++++ END ++++++++
```

Comment: works fine here (even though you might want to use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) and ignore onaddstream. What does about:webrtc show in Firefox when it does not work?

Comment: I tried on three different computers (Linux, Windows and Mac). The only common thing between the computers is the network. I will try to test with different connection.

Which Firefox version do you have? I tried with 57 and 52.5

Comment: works in 57, 58, 59 and ESR (52.5).Does https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/ work on the same machine?

Comment: I see the camera image but only on the first video element, the second one remains empty and log is exactly the same as on my example...

Comment: I compared console logs from Chrome and Firefox and I see that in Firefox the function `gotRemoteStream` is not triggered. It's assigned to the `ontrack` event, so the behavior is exactly the same as on my example.

Comment: Does it happen with a fresh firefox profile? That would imply an extension that is blocking WebRTC, however I am not aware of anything that would cause errors at socket level.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with completely fresh installation... What's more I see the same behavior on Safari browser, which since July 2017 should support WebRTC